# Can I use "to verb" form instead of "that clause" form in this sentence?

Tags: difference

> Eating good food ensures ***that we*** stay healthy.

This is the example sentence of "ensure" in my dictionary.

I am curious if the sentence below is possible and have the same meaning.

> Eating good food ensures ***us to*** stay healthy.

Comment: No, you can't. "Ensure" is a TRANSITIVE VERB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we **can** use "ensure":

> Negotiators ensured **that** *the treaty was* a significant change in direction.
>
> The lifejacket had almost certainly ensured *her survival*.

We **can't** use a to-infinitive after the direct object when using "ensure."

Comment: I've been working on it in many ways, but I haven't been able to find the exact answer for days. I'm sorry I don't know what you're saying honestly, I mean.. so you mean.. is it possible to say "Eating good food ensures us stay healthy." without "to"?

Comment: @Fringetos no, it's not. But it is possible to say "eating good food ensures that we stay healthy." It's also possible to say "eating good food ensures our health."

Comment: I have one more question. What about this sentence "Eating good food ensures staying healthy." or "Eating good food ensures to stay healthy."? Is it possible in grammar? Maybe I don't know exactly what "ensure" means.

Comment: @Fringetos you'd better not use "to" after "ensure." "Eating good food ensures good health" is a pretty formal way to say that "if you eat good food, you'll be healthy." If something ensures good health, then good health is almost certain to happen, and good food makes it possible.